# Cypress: Cannot create property 'errors' on string

Tags: cypress

I created a sample project and the URL I wish to navigate is https://www.nasa.gov/ but it fails with the error 'Cannot create property 'errors' on string ''... I was able to run this earlier but now all of a sudden, it is throwing this error.. Anyone experience this before?

```
1
visithttps://www.nasa.gov/
(xhr)GET 200 /api/1/record/menu/main-menu.json
(xhr)GET 404 /api/2/ubernode/484058
(xhr)GET 200 /api/2/ubernode/475095
(xhr)GET 404 /api/2/ubernode/484009
(xhr)GET 200 /api/2/ubernode/_search?size=24&from=0&sort=promo-date-time:desc&q=((ubernode-type:feature OR ubernode-type:image OR ubernode-type:press_release OR ubernode-type:collection_asset OR ubernode-type:mediacast) AND (routes:1))&_source_include=promo-date-time,master-image,nid,title,topics,missions,collections,other-tags,ubernode-type,primary-tag,secondary-tag,cardfeed-title,type,collection-asset-link,link-or-attachment,pr-leader-sentence,image-feature-caption,attachments,uri
(xhr)GET 200 /api/2/ubernode/_search?size=24&from=0&sort=promo-date-time%3Adesc&q=((ubernode-type%3Afeature%20OR%20ubernode-type%3Aimage%20OR%20ubernode-type%3Apress_release%20OR%20ubernode-type%3Acollection_asset%20OR%20ubernode-type%3Amediacast)%20AND%20(routes%3A1))&_source_include=promo-date-time%2Cmaster-image%2Cnid%2Ctitle%2Ctopics%2Cmissions%2Ccollections%2Cother-tags%2Cubernode-type%2Cprimary-tag%2Csecondary-tag%2Ccardfeed-title%2Ctype%2Ccollection-asset-link%2Clink-or-attachment%2Cpr-leader-sentence%2Cimage-feature-caption%2Cattachments%2Curi
(xhr)POST 200 https://www.google-analytics.com/collect
(xhr)POST 200 https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/j/collect?t=dc&aip=1&_r=3&v=1&_v=j98&tid=UA-33523145-1&cid=1911079010.1668736398&jid=1122556433&gjid=1361169494&_gid=2094514542.1668736398&_u=YGBAgQABAAAAAEAAo~&z=729024113
(uncaught exception)TypeError: Cannot create property 'errors' on string '<!DOCTYPE html> <html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr" prefix="content: http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/ dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/ foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/ og: http://ogp.me/ns# rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema# sioc: http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns# sioct: http://rdfs.org/sioc/types# skos: http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core# xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <meta name="dc.creator" content="NASA Content Administrator" /> <meta name="dc.title" content="404" /> <meta property="twitter:url" content="/404" /> <meta property="twitter:site:id" content="11348282" /> <meta name="dc.date" content="2015-04-17T21:32-04:00" /> <meta name="dc.language" content="und" /> <link rel="profile" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab" /> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" /> <meta name="dc.format" content="text/html" /> <meta name="dc.type" content="Text" /> <meta name="dc.identifier" content="/404" /> <meta property="twitter:site" content="@NASA" /> <meta property="twitter:title" content="404" /> <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.nasa.gov/404" /> <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.nasa.gov" /> <meta property="og:title" content="404" /> <meta property="twitter:image" content="http://www.nasa.gov" /> <meta name="generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" /> <meta property="og:type" content="article" /> <meta property="og:site_name" content="NASA" /> <link rel="shortlink" href="/404" /> <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" /> <link rel="canonical" href="/404" /> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0" /> <title>404 | NASA</title> <meta name="nasa/config/environment" content="%7B%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22nasa%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22development%22%2C%22baseURL%22%3A%22/%22%2C%22locationType%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22EmberENV%22%3A%7B%22FEATURES%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22APP%22%3A%7B%22LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION%22%3Atrue%2C%22LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22contentSecurityPolicyHeader%22%3A%22Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only%22%2C%22contentSecurityPolicy%22%3A%7B%22default-src%22%3A%22%27none%27%22%2C%22script-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%20%27unsafe-eval%27%22%2C%22font-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22connect-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22img-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22style-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22media-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%7D%2C%22exportApplicationGlobal%22%3Atrue%7D" /> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" /> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon.png"> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png"> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png"> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png"> <style> @import url("/sites/all/modules/custom/scald_before_after_image/scald_before_after_image.css?onjf4k"); @import url("/sites/all/modules/custom/scald_htmlsnippet/scald_htmlsnippet.css?onjf4k"); @import url("/sites/all/modules/custom/scald_iframe/scald_iframe.css?onjf4k"); </style> <style> @import url("/sites/all/modules/contributed/jreject/jReject/css/jquery.reject.css?onjf4k"); </style> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/css/vendor.css?onjf4k" media="all" /> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/css/nasa.css?onjf4k" media="all" /> <script language="javascript" id="_fed_an_ua_tag" src="https://dap.digitalgov.gov/Universal-Federated-Analytics-Min.js?agency=NASA&yt=true&dclink=true"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> ;(function (g) { var d = document, i, am = d.createElement('script'), h = d.head || d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0], aex = { "src": "//gateway.foresee.com/sites/nasa-gov/production/gateway.min.js", "type": "text/javascript", "async": "true", "data-vendor": "acs", "data-role": "gateway" }; for (var attr in aex){am.setAttribute(attr, aex[attr]);}h.appendChild(am);g[fsr] || (g[fsr] = function () {var aT = '_' + fsr + 'stk';g[aT] = g[aT] || [];g[aT].push(arguments);}); })(window); </script> <script src="/sites/all/modules/fb_instant_articles/modules/fb_instant_articles_display/js/admin.js?onjf4k"></script> <script src="/sites/all/modules/scald_twitter/scald_twitter.js?onjf4k"></script> <script>window.forcedRoute = "error";</script> <script>window.Drupal = {behaviors: {}};</script> <script src="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/js/vendor.js?onjf4k"></script> <script src="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/js/nasa.js?onjf4k"></script> <script src="/sites/all/modules/contributed/jreject/jReject/js/jquery.reject.js?onjf4k"></script> </head> <body class="html not-front not-logged-in page-node page-node- page-node-355192 node-type-ember-page section-404" class="Array"> <div class="l-page ember-init-hide"> <header class="l-header container-fluid" role="banner"></header> <div class="l-main"> <div class="l-content container-fluid" id="main" role="main"> <article about="/404" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document" role="article" class="node node--ember-page node--promoted node--full node--ember-page--full"> <header> <span property="dc:title" content="404" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span> </header> <div class="node__content"> </div> </article> </div> </div> <footer class="l-footer container-fluid" role="contentinfo"></footer> </div> <script> (function($) { $.reject({ display: ["msie", "firefox", "safari", "opera", "chrome", "gcf"], reject: {
msie5: true, msie6: true, msie7: true, msie8: true, msie9: true, firefox2: true, firefox3: true, firefox4: true, firefox5: true, firefox6: true, firefox7: true, firefox8: true, firefox9: true, safari1: true, safari2: true, safari3: true, safari4: true, opera1: true, opera2: true, opera3: true, opera4: true, opera5: true, opera6: true, opera7: true, opera8: true, opera9: true }, imagePath: '/sites/all/modules/contributed/jreject/jReject/images/', enable: true, header: "Did you know that your Internet Browser is out of date?", paragraph1: "To ensure that all features of NASA.gov work effectively, please upgrade to the latest version of one of these web browsers. <br /><br />For Internet Explorer users: The site will only be fully functional on version 11 with compatibility mode turned off. If you're using version 11 and you're seeing this message, compatibility mode is turned on in your browser. If you need compatibility mode turned on to use other sites or applications, you'll need to use another browser to see the full NASA site.", paragraph2: "Just click on the icons to get to the download page:", closeMessage: "By closing this window you acknowledge that your experience on this website may be degraded.", closeLink: "Close This Window", closeURL: "#", close: true, closeESC: true, closeCookie: true, overlayBgColor: "#000", overlayOpacity: 0.8, fadeInTime: "fast", fadeOutTime: "fast" }); })(jQuery);</script> </body> </html> '
(uncaught exception)TypeError: Cannot create property 'errors' on string '<!DOCTYPE html> <html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr" prefix="content: http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/ dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/ foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/ og: http://ogp.me/ns# rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema# sioc: http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns# sioct: http://rdfs.org/sioc/types# skos: http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core# xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <meta name="dc.creator" content="NASA Content Administrator" /> <meta name="dc.title" content="404" /> <meta property="twitter:url" content="/404" /> <meta property="twitter:site:id" content="11348282" /> <meta name="dc.date" content="2015-04-17T21:32-04:00" /> <meta name="dc.language" content="und" /> <link rel="profile" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab" /> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" /> <meta name="dc.format" content="text/html" /> <meta name="dc.type" content="Text" /> <meta name="dc.identifier" content="/404" /> <meta property="twitter:site" content="@NASA" /> <meta property="twitter:title" content="404" /> <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.nasa.gov/404" /> <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.nasa.gov" /> <meta property="og:title" content="404" /> <meta property="twitter:image" content="http://www.nasa.gov" /> <meta name="generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" /> <meta property="og:type" content="article" /> <meta property="og:site_name" content="NASA" /> <link rel="shortlink" href="/404" /> <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" /> <link rel="canonical" href="/404" /> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0" /> <title>404 | NASA</title> <meta name="nasa/config/environment" content="%7B%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22nasa%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22development%22%2C%22baseURL%22%3A%22/%22%2C%22locationType%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22EmberENV%22%3A%7B%22FEATURES%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22APP%22%3A%7B%22LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION%22%3Atrue%2C%22LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22contentSecurityPolicyHeader%22%3A%22Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only%22%2C%22contentSecurityPolicy%22%3A%7B%22default-src%22%3A%22%27none%27%22%2C%22script-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%20%27unsafe-eval%27%22%2C%22font-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22connect-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22img-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22style-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22media-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%7D%2C%22exportApplicationGlobal%22%3Atrue%7D" /> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" /> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon.png"> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png"> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png"> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png"> <style> @import url("/sites/all/modules/custom/scald_before_after_image/scald_before_after_image.css?onjf4k"); @import url("/sites/all/modules/custom/scald_htmlsnippet/scald_htmlsnippet.css?onjf4k"); @import url("/sites/all/modules/custom/scald_iframe/scald_iframe.css?onjf4k"); </style> <style> @import url("/sites/all/modules/contributed/jreject/jReject/css/jquery.reject.css?onjf4k"); </style> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/css/vendor.css?onjf4k" media="all" /> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/css/nasa.css?onjf4k" media="all" /> <script language="javascript" id="_fed_an_ua_tag" src="https://dap.digitalgov.gov/Universal-Federated-Analytics-Min.js?agency=NASA&yt=true&dclink=true"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> ;(function (g) { var d = document, i, am = d.createElement('script'), h = d.head || d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0], aex = { "src": "//gateway.foresee.com/sites/nasa-gov/production/gateway.min.js", "type": "text/javascript", "async": "true", "data-vendor": "acs", "data-role": "gateway" }; for (var attr in aex){am.setAttribute(attr, aex[attr]);}h.appendChild(am);g[fsr] || (g[fsr] = function () {var aT = '_' + fsr + 'stk';g[aT] = g[aT] || [];g[aT].push(arguments);}); })(window); </script> <script src="/sites/all/modules/fb_instant_articles/modules/fb_instant_articles_display/js/admin.js?onjf4k"></script> <script src="/sites/all/modules/scald_twitter/scald_twitter.js?onjf4k"></script> <script>window.forcedRoute = "error";</script> <script>window.Drupal = {behaviors: {}};</script> <script src="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/js/vendor.js?onjf4k"></script> <script src="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/js/nasa.js?onjf4k"></script> <script src="/sites/all/modules/contributed/jreject/jReject/js/jquery.reject.js?onjf4k"></script> </head> <body class="html not-front not-logged-in page-node page-node- page-node-355192 node-type-ember-page section-404" class="Array"> <div class="l-page ember-init-hide"> <header class="l-header container-fluid" role="banner"></header> <div class="l-main"> <div class="l-content container-fluid" id="main" role="main"> <article about="/404" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document" role="article" class="node node--ember-page node--promoted node--full node--ember-page--full"> <header> <span property="dc:title" content="404" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span> </header> <div class="node__content"> </div> </article> </div> </div> <footer class="l-footer container-fluid" role="contentinfo"></footer> </div> <script> (function($) { $.reject({ display: ["msie", "firefox", "safari", "opera", "chrome", "gcf"], reject: {
msie5: true, msie6: true, msie7: true, msie8: true, msie9: true, firefox2: true, firefox3: true, firefox4: true, firefox5: true, firefox6: true, firefox7: true, firefox8: true, firefox9: true, safari1: true, safari2: true, safari3: true, safari4: true, opera1: true, opera2: true, opera3: true, opera4: true, opera5: true, opera6: true, opera7: true, opera8: true, opera9: true }, imagePath: '/sites/all/modules/contributed/jreject/jReject/images/', enable: true, header: "Did you know that your Internet Browser is out of date?", paragraph1: "To ensure that all features of NASA.gov work effectively, please upgrade to the latest version of one of these web browsers. <br /><br />For Internet Explorer users: The site will only be fully functional on version 11 with compatibility mode turned off. If you're using version 11 and you're seeing this message, compatibility mode is turned on in your browser. If you need compatibility mode turned on to use other sites or applications, you'll need to use another browser to see the full NASA site.", paragraph2: "Just click on the icons to get to the download page:", closeMessage: "By closing this window you acknowledge that your experience on this website may be degraded.", closeLink: "Close This Window", closeURL: "#", close: true, closeESC: true, closeCookie: true, overlayBgColor: "#000", overlayOpacity: 0.8, fadeInTime: "fast", fadeOutTime: "fast" }); })(jQuery);</script> </body> </html> '
(xhr)GET 200 /api/2/term/4595
(xhr)GET 200 /api/2/term/3627
(xhr)GET 200 /api/2/term/3169
(xhr)GET 200 /api/2/term/3121
(xhr)GET 200 /api/2/term/3131
(xhr)GET 200 /api/2/term/4543
(xhr)GET 200 /api/2/term/4515
(xhr)GET 200 /api/2/term/6893
(xhr)GET 200 /api/2/term/3643
(xhr)GET 200 /api/2/term/3152
(xhr)GET 200 /api/2/term/3119
TypeError
The following error originated from your application code, not from Cypress.

> Cannot create property 'errors' on string '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr" prefix="content: http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/ dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/ foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/ og: http://ogp.me/ns# rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema# sioc: http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns# sioct: http://rdfs.org/sioc/types# skos: http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core# xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="dc.creator" content="NASA Content Administrator" />
<meta name="dc.title" content="404" />
<meta property="twitter:url" content="/404" />
<meta property="twitter:site:id" content="11348282" />
<meta name="dc.date" content="2015-04-17T21:32-04:00" />
<meta name="dc.language" content="und" />
<link rel="profile" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<meta name="dc.format" content="text/html" />
<meta name="dc.type" content="Text" />
<meta name="dc.identifier" content="/404" />
<meta property="twitter:site" content="@NASA" />
<meta property="twitter:title" content="404" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.nasa.gov/404" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.nasa.gov" />
<meta property="og:title" content="404" />
<meta property="twitter:image" content="http://www.nasa.gov" />
<meta name="generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="NASA" />
<link rel="shortlink" href="/404" />
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<link rel="canonical" href="/404" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0" />
<title>404 | NASA</title>
<meta name="nasa/config/environment" content="%7B%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22nasa%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22development%22%2C%22baseURL%22%3A%22/%22%2C%22locationType%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22EmberENV%22%3A%7B%22FEATURES%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22APP%22%3A%7B%22LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION%22%3Atrue%2C%22LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22contentSecurityPolicyHeader%22%3A%22Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only%22%2C%22contentSecurityPolicy%22%3A%7B%22default-src%22%3A%22%27none%27%22%2C%22script-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%20%27unsafe-eval%27%22%2C%22font-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22connect-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22img-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22style-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22media-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%7D%2C%22exportApplicationGlobal%22%3Atrue%7D" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/images/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<style>
@import url("/sites/all/modules/custom/scald_before_after_image/scald_before_after_image.css?onjf4k");
@import url("/sites/all/modules/custom/scald_htmlsnippet/scald_htmlsnippet.css?onjf4k");
@import url("/sites/all/modules/custom/scald_iframe/scald_iframe.css?onjf4k");
</style>
<style>
@import url("/sites/all/modules/contributed/jreject/jReject/css/jquery.reject.css?onjf4k");
</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/css/vendor.css?onjf4k" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/css/nasa.css?onjf4k" media="all" />
<script language="javascript" id="_fed_an_ua_tag" src="https://dap.digitalgov.gov/Universal-Federated-Analytics-Min.js?agency=NASA&yt=true&dclink=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function (g) {
var d = document, i, am = d.createElement('script'), h = d.head || d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
aex = {
"src": "//gateway.foresee.com/sites/nasa-gov/production/gateway.min.js",
"type": "text/javascript",
"async": "true",
"data-vendor": "acs",
"data-role": "gateway"
};
for (var attr in aex){am.setAttribute(attr, aex[attr]);}h.appendChild(am);g[fsr] || (g[fsr] = function () {var aT = '_' + fsr + 'stk';g[aT] = g[aT] || [];g[aT].push(arguments);});
})(window);
</script>
<script src="/sites/all/modules/fb_instant_articles/modules/fb_instant_articles_display/js/admin.js?onjf4k"></script>
<script src="/sites/all/modules/scald_twitter/scald_twitter.js?onjf4k"></script>
<script>window.forcedRoute = "error";</script>
<script>window.Drupal = {behaviors: {}};</script>
<script src="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/js/vendor.js?onjf4k"></script>
<script src="/sites/all/themes/custom/nasatwo/js/nasa.js?onjf4k"></script>
<script src="/sites/all/modules/contributed/jreject/jReject/js/jquery.reject.js?onjf4k"></script>
</head>
<body class="html not-front not-logged-in page-node page-node- page-node-355192 node-type-ember-page section-404" class="Array">
<div class="l-page ember-init-hide">
<header class="l-header container-fluid" role="banner"></header>
<div class="l-main">
<div class="l-content container-fluid" id="main" role="main">
<article about="/404" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document" role="article" class="node node--ember-page node--promoted node--full node--ember-page--full">
<header>
<span property="dc:title" content="404" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span>
</header>

<div class="node__content">
</div>
</article>
</div>
</div>
<footer class="l-footer container-fluid" role="contentinfo"></footer>
</div>

<script>  (function($) {
$.reject({
display: ["msie", "firefox", "safari", "opera", "chrome", "gcf"],
reject: {

msie5: true, msie6: true, msie7: true, msie8: true, msie9: true, firefox2: true, firefox3: true, firefox4: true, firefox5: true, firefox6: true, firefox7: true, firefox8: true, firefox9: true, safari1: true, safari2: true, safari3: true, safari4: true, opera1: true, opera2: true, opera3: true, opera4: true, opera5: true, opera6: true, opera7: true, opera8: true, opera9: true
},
imagePath: '/sites/all/modules/contributed/jreject/jReject/images/',
enable: true, header: "Did you know that your Internet Browser is out of date?", paragraph1: "To ensure that all features of NASA.gov work effectively, please upgrade to the latest version of one of these web browsers. <br /><br />For Internet Explorer users: The site will only be fully functional on version 11 with compatibility mode turned off. If you're using version 11 and you're seeing this message, compatibility mode is turned on in your browser. If you need compatibility mode turned on to use other sites or applications, you'll need to use another browser to see the full NASA site.", paragraph2: "Just click on the icons to get to the download page:", closeMessage: "By closing this window you acknowledge that your experience on this website may be degraded.", closeLink: "Close This Window", closeURL: "#", close: true, closeESC: true, closeCookie: true, overlayBgColor: "#000", overlayOpacity: 0.8, fadeInTime: "fast", fadeOutTime: "fast"
});
})(jQuery);</script>

</body>
</html>
'
```

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your application it will automatically fail the current test.

This behavior is configurable, and you can choose to turn this off by listening to the uncaught:exception event.Learn more

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to ignore the exception

```js
cy.visit('https://www.nasa.gov/')
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    return false
})
```